# Why was this spam flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam

Some days ago I was getting started with writing T4 templates with Visual Studio, and as many I arrived to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420766/3932049).

Then, I saw [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159220/3932049)

> In my case Resharper wins again ,with the help of ForTea Plugin.

This is not only an extremely low quality answer (absolutely nothing to support the statement, just 2 links), but also a dual spam (one for ReSharper, one for the ForTea plugin), and it's also not a real answer.

I wonder why, then, my flag was declined, since the spam flag reads "**exists only to promote a product or service**".

Comment: The question is basically a resource request, the answer gives them that.  So it is not unsolicited.

Comment: @NathanOliver how is it that a question asking how something can be done is a resource request?

Comment: The question literally isn't but people are offering alternatives to visual studio or plugins to get it to work.  IMHO it is the question that is the problem and it should be closed for being to broad.

Comment: There is no reason to believe this product was recommended in bad faith or that the OP stands to benefit from this recommendation, so it's not spam by SE definitions.

Comment: By that logic, wouldn't you have to flag just about anything that contained a tool recommendation (whether the OP personally profited from recommending the tool or not)? If they're not affiliated with the company producing the product or otherwise personally profiting from recommending it and the product is actually applicable to the problem at hand, there's no reason to flag it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Overflow has an unusually specific definition of spam: it has to be *self-promotion*. There's no evidence that this is; it's just a normal low-quality answer, begotten by a correspondingly low-quality recommendation question, like all of the other answers that question has received.

But don't think that means you should flag it as "low quality" or "not an answer" or whatever, either. Those flags just mean "please delete", and this answer does not need to be deleted. It *is* an answer to the question, and even if those links were to go down, the answer still gives the name of a plug-in that you can search for.

What the answer really needs is editing. At minimum, an edit should fix the grammar. Even better, an edit would add a sentence or two explaining what this tool actually is and how it solves the problem (but that would require someone familiar with the tool, and I am not that person; evidently, you aren't either).

Comment: This is basically like saying that any question can be answered with a product link. The question asks whether there is a way to do something, a real answer would be "yes, there is, but you create it yourself or use this product that does it in this/that way", not a useless "go buy this product because I like it"

Comment: Any question that asks for a tool *can* be answered with a product link. This is one of the problems with such questions. I don't understand how "yes, there is, but you create it yourself or go buy this product" is any different than "go buy this product that does what you want". I agree that the "because I like it" part is problematic, but (A) it doesn't actually say that, and (B) that's fixable via editing, as I mentioned.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto by that logic, why didn't you flag the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420766/how-can-i-get-intellisense-in-a-t4-template/3509123#3509123) as spam?  It is no different than this one you flagged.

Comment: Any question that asks for a tool **should be marked as off topic as per the site rules**, not answered with a product link. Also, the question does not asks for a tool, but whether something can or cannot be done

Comment: @psubsee2003 I would have if the one I flagged hadn't been declined

Comment: Oh boy. Not this again. Asking whether or not something can be done is a stupid question, because the answer is just going to be "yes". That doesn't help anyone. When people ask questions phrased in that way, what they really mean is, *how* can I do this? And the answer to that is, almost always, use this tool that is designed to do it for you. There really isn't anything wrong with that, other than it tends to attract low-quality answers that lack the type of explanation we prefer to see. If you have a problem with this, focus your ire on the question.

Comment: I'll take this into account for the future, but I find it very awkward that you can promote any product while it's not yours

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you can promote a product that is yours as well, as long as you disclose it and don't answer every related question with the same product promotion

Comment: You can even promote your own products, [as long as you disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: +1 for use of the word *begotten*.